# Angular 14 + Load Component Dynamically by name or selector (string) + lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-dynamic-components

I want to load component from different lazy loaded module as per my menu selected. My menu comes from database table. say as ex. as below:

| MenuComponent | MenuID |
| --- | --- |
| Customer | 1001 |
| Supplier | 1002 |

I have tried one scenario as given [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b2qbuj). Problem is consider as below case:

1. When `Angular CLI` `Enable IVY=false` then it work successfully (Angular 12) by component name but if set to true then it gives error

> Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type'.
> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Type': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 5 more

As per searching found that in latest version of angular `ComponentFactoryResolver` is deprecated & now need to inject component using `createComponent` method.

```
constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {}

var factories = Array.from(this.resolver['_factories'].keys());
```

2. Now main issue is that i am not able to understand how can create component type object using `MenuID` that decide to inject component along with lazy loaded module.

> createComponent(component: Type, options: { environmentInjector: EnvironmentInjector; hostElement?: Element; elementInjector?: Injector; projectableNodes?: Node[][]; })

I don't want to maintain static object which contains menuid & component type object.

I have tried below [approch](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b2qbuj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontrol-factory.directive.ts).

Take a look as reference which import as static [Reference](https://github.com/danmt/dynamic-component-loader)

Expected Result is as below:
[image]

When user click on customer  then load component of customer by name or selector name of customer component.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I know what you want but you can make those component keys as route paths, and lazy load modules with them.

```js
// Your app routes

const routes = [
  {
    path: 'Home',
    loadChildren: () => import("./home/home.module").then((m) => m.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'Customer',
    loadChildren: () => import("./customer/customer.module").then((m) => m.CustomerModule),
  },
]
```

```js
// home-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: HomeComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }

];
```

Comment: problem is not with it. i need to inject componect runtime. refer stackbliz link. thanks for replay

Comment: I still don't understand your use case unfortunately

Comment: basically i want to load component & module dynamically. so using 'selector' string of component i want to load it. suppose i have click on customer button (all button existence come from database) at that time load module using selector of customer component.

Comment: where are component files that you want to load? Are you getting them from somewhere other than your project?

Comment: Just give you actual situation. In project forms are divided with separate module like 'CustomerModule' & inside it having a 'CustomerComponent'. same fashion all the component available with their respective module.

Now, All the button's come dynamically like Customer, Supplier. When user click on customer then load component of customer by component name or selector name of customer component.

Comment: I have done above mention functionality in Angular Version 12 using Compile. But compile is deprecated in version 14. Now i want to move my project in latest version with due to this issue, not able to do.

Comment: I still don't understand the difference between your desire and using lazy loading. With lazy loading the module files are only loaded when the route is visited, so you basically load them dynamically.

Comment: right but on any event fire you have write some component name statically that you need to load. in my case using menuID need to load that component,